# Button works in simulator for not in App

Tags: iphone, button, ios-simulator

I have a few different views in my App, all of which are viewed by tapping different buttons.  All the buttons work on the simulator, but when I run the app on the device only one button does not work.  I went over and over my code and re coded that one button and re-connected it in IB to make sure that i did not mess something dumb up, but it still freezes my app.
When the bad button is tapped the App will freeze but not shut off and the only way to unfreeze it is to press the home button.

Any thoughts on why this might be happing only to this one button?

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, any log files you have pertaining to the crash, or even a screenshot of how it's set up, it's hard to say. Can you post more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!  It was something really dumb!  In the view that is loaded when the button is tapped there is a picker.  What was happening is that I have a BOOL value that needs to be set to true when the button is tapped and I forgot to set it.  Without that BOOL value being set the picker was not being loaded the right way.